# counting value in different type(group)

Tags: php, mysql

i have a problem where i want to count the value based on the type..e.g

```
 a 5
 a 5
 b 7
```

the output: a = 10 and b = 7
and it will count++ every time the data change to c, ... , z
this is what i got so far...

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
    $num = $num+1;

 echo "there are ".$row['COUNT(data)']." on ".$row['date']." items";
    $total+= $row['COUNT(date)'];
            ?>
<? echo "<br/>"; 
}
echo "<br/> the data has " . $total ;

?>
```

Comment: Do you want the sum of values with same type?

Comment: actually this is my output

there are 4 on 2012-05-15 15:54:25 items
there are 5 on 2012-05-22 13:24:42 items
there are 1 on 2012-05-22 13:25:02 items
there are 1 on 2012-05-22 13:25:29 items

i count it and it become 11 but i want the output become:-
2012-05-22 = 7 and 2012-05-15 = 4...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your columns are called `type` and `value` in this table...

```
     SELECT type, sum(VALUE) as value
       FROM table
   GROUP BY type
   ORDER BY type
```

should give you a resultset with each type and value.

But your question isn't perfectly clear about what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use below

```
SELECT field01, sum(field02) as Total_Sum
FROM myTable
GROUP BY field01
```

considering `field01` is a,a,b and `field02` is 5,5,6...

Answer (score 0):

You definitely want to use `GROUP BY` on the SQL side, but grouping by datetime/timestamp for just the date portion will get expensive with any sizable amount of data.

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(1) as `total`, 
    DATE(date_col) as `date` 
FROM  table 
GROUP BY DATE(date_col)
```

I have a table with roughly 1.6m records. This query (with an `ORDER BY` and a `LIMIT 5`) took roughly 2 seconds on a 512MB VM. It ain't slow.. but it's not fast either.